# Why is it not possible to access the size of a new[]'d array?

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator, delete-operator

When you allocate an array using `new []`, why can't you find out the size of that array from the pointer? It must be known at run time, otherwise `delete []` wouldn't know how much memory to free.

Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: A simple good design doesn't need to know - in a complex case you have to do a lot of the management yourself.  There are generaly debug functions for your compiler that will tell you - but if you need this your design is probably wrong.

Comment: I've often wondered why you never see an allocator that doesn't know the size, and requires it to be passed on deletion. because how often have you ever come to delete a block of memory and not been able to easily calculate it's size?   I guess there must never have really been a benefit to implementing a system with this limitation...

Comment: It would probably place unnecessary restrictions on the implementation of such a low-level operation. After all you did know how much you asked for when you allocated the array, so there's no pressing need of the runtime to be able to tell you that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a typical implementation the size of dynamic memory block is somehow stored in the block itself - this is true. But there's no standard way to access this information. (Implementations may provide implementation-specific ways to access it). This is how it is with `malloc/free`, this is how it is with `new[]/delete[]`.

In fact, in a typical implementation raw memory allocations for `new[]/delete[]` calls are eventually processed by some implementation-specific `malloc/free`-like pair, which means that `delete[]` doesn't really have to care about how much memory to deallocate: it simply calls that internal `free` (or whatever it is named), which takes care of that.

What `delete[]` does need to know though is how many elements to *destruct* in situations when array element type has non-trivial destructor. And this is what your question is about - *the number of array elements*, not the size of the block (these two are not the same, the block could be larger than really required for the array itself). For this reason, the number of elements in the array is normally also stored inside the block by `new[]` and later retrieved by `delete[]` to perform the proper array element destruction. There are no standard ways to access this number either.

(This means that in general case, a typical memory block allocated by `new[]` will independently, simultaneously store *both* the physical block size in bytes *and* the array element count. These values are stored by different levels of C++ memory allocation mechanism - raw memory allocator and `new[]` itself respectively - and don't interact with each other in any way).

However, note that for the above reasons the array element count is normally only stored when the array element type has non-trivial destructor. I.e. this count is not always present. This is one of the reasons why providing a standard way to access that data is not feasible: you'd either have to store it always (which wastes memory) or restrict its availability by destructor type (which is confusing).

To illustrate the above, when you create an array of `int`s

```
int *array = new int[100];
```

the size of the array (i.e. `100`) is *not* normally stored by `new[]` since `delete[]` does not care about it (`int` has no destructor). The physical size of the block in bytes (like, 400 bytes or more) is normally stored in the block by the raw memory allocator (and used by raw memory deallocator invoked by `delete[]`), but it can easily turn out to be 420 for some implementation-specific reason. So, this size is basically useless for you, since you won't be able to derive the exact original array size from it.

Comment: Yes, the memory allocator may not know the size of the array. It may have returned a block of the next largest available size and does not even care that you only used 75% of it.

Answer (score 7):

You most likely can access it, but it would require intimate knowledge of your allocator and would not be portable.  The C++ standard doesn't specify *how* implementations store this data, so there's no consistent method for obtaining it.   I believe it's left unspecified because different allocators may wish to store it in different ways for efficiency purposes.

Comment: Still it would been cool if the Standard had specified a `len(...)` operator, so its possible to get the size of an array using that operator (and the authors can implement that len operator like they want to) ... :(

Comment: @smelin Isn't that what `std::vector<>` is for?

Answer (score 5):

It makes sense, as for example the size of the allocated block may not necessarily be the same size as the array. While [it is true](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/03/66660.aspx) that `new[]` may store the number of elements (calling each elements destructor), it doesn't have to as it wouldn't be required for a empty destructor. There is also no standard way ([C++ FAQ Lite 1](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html#faq-38.7), [C++ FAQ Lite 2](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html#faq-38.8)) of implementing where `new[]` stores the array length as each method has its pros and cons.

In other words, it allows allocations to as fast an cheap as possible by not specifying anything about the implementation. (If the implementation has to store the size of the array as well as the size of the allocated block every time, it wastes memory that you may not need).

Answer (score 3):

Simply put, the C++ standard does not require support for this.  It is possible that if you know enough about the internals of your compiler, you can figure out how to access this information, but that would *generally* be considered bad practice.  Note that there may be a difference in memory layout for heap-allocated arrays and stack-allocated arrays.

Remember that essentially what you are talking about here are C-style arrays, too -- even though `new` and `delete` are C++ operators -- and the behavior is inherited from C.  If you want a C++ "array" that is sized, you should be using the STL (e.g. std::vector, std::deque).

Comment: Yeah, I don't generally use C-style arrays -- it was just a general question as it (if it were possible) saves some memory in a lot of cases.