# Size of array (new[])

Tags: c++, arrays, new-operator

In debug heap I can get size of array, which was created by `new[]`:

```
int size = *((int *)((char *)ptr - 16));
```

It is working correctly if the size of the array is less than 28 (but I don't know why? 0_0).

Does this trick working in release mode (not using debug heap)?

How I can get size of the array (100% working and stable)?

Comment: Why do you need to get the size of an array?

Comment: You could use a vector instead. Its size can be retrieved though `std::vector::size()`.

Comment: [You can't do that reliably/universally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405722/why-cant-you-access-the-size-of-a-newd-array).

Comment: not portable, not reliable, implementation defined... stop doing it.

Comment: Just to add to the consensus - don't do that

Answer (score 11):

You are relying on an implementation detail. That's how your particular implementation stores the size of the memory region where the array is placed. As you already see, the size of the memory region may be bigger than the size of the allocated array.

If you need to know the size of an array allocated with `new[]`, you'll have to keep that value around.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
std::vector< int > array( 1024 ); // allocate 1024 element array.
int size = array.size();
int sizeInBytes = size * sizeof( int );
```

;)

It really is the best way what you are trying to do is take adavantage of something which is COMPLETELY compiler/library dependent ... Its a really bad thing to do, in general, as your code becomes completely unportable not even mentioning that the next version of your compiler may come with a different memory allocation implementation which breaks what you are trying to do ...

Comment: -1 I know this is what he should probably do, but you don't know that for sure and it's not what he's asking. Also, it's really frustrating to receive answers like this.

Comment: +1 When the OP is asking how to shoot himself in the foot, "aim better" is not the best answer. Not using a loaded gun, is.

Comment: @BoPersson: Yes, as long as the answer also explains *why* the current approach is incorrect.  Originally this response did not, which is what Pubby was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

Any way that involves mining something from the CRT is undefined and cannot work 100%.
Your only way is to override operator new[] that will store the size somewhere defined, like allocating bigger object with size prefix.

Comment: `Any way that involves mining something from the CRT is undefined` ... it is not *undefined*, it is *unspecified*. If it were the former, the implementation itself would have one hell of a time keeping track of the memory it has allocated.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you're using an implementation detail to figure out the size of the allocated array. You've managed to figure out that if you walk back 16 bytes from the beginning of the pointer returned by `new[]` you can get the size of the array.

16 bytes of extra allocation seems excessive and this most likely will not be the case if you compile the release version of your application. The implementation is probably allocating some extra bytes before and after the length you've requested and filling it with magic values to help catch your code overrunning the bounds of the array. This extra space will probably not be allocated in the release version.

Also, you yourself mention that if the array size is smaller than some threshold the 16 byte number does not seem valid anymore. It is possible that if you allocate bigger objects than whatever you're allocating right now, you'll have to walk back even further to get to the size.

So, the solutions available to you are:

- Continue allocating using `new[]` and keep the size around for later use
- Use `std::vector` and get the size using `std::vector::size`
- If know the size of the array beforehand, and don't need to resize it, use `std::array`. Note that this option does not allocate memory on the heap (unless of course you `new` the `std::array` itself)